# Easy way to extract IP and referer from nginx log file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

How to find ip and referer which contains facebook/instagram/twitter/etc using awk or others possible commands, to get this:

```
1.2.3.4 https://l.instagram.com/
4.3.2.1 https://facebook.com/
```

Nginx log file has standart format:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [02/Oct/2021:06:07:08 +0300 - -] 200 "GET /index.php HTTP/2.0" 6620 "https://l.instagram.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-N950F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I'm using

```
awk '{print $1}' access.log
```

and

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' access.log
```

But I don't know how to get ip and referer together.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[ "]' '{print $1, $16}' file
1.2.3.4 https://l.instagram.com/
```

Comment: For strict compliance I added `($16 ~ /instagram\.|facebook\./)`. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Using gnu-awk you could specify the fields with [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) and using a pattern.

The fields in the example are either from `[...]` or `"..."` or 1 or more non whitspace chars.

For that you could write a pattern with an alternation `|` to match either of  those 3 variations.

```
\\[[^][]*]|"([^"]*)"|\\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7LNIE9/1)

If the url should match either instagram or facebook, you can use another pattern and remove the double quotes from the match. The column values are now 1 and 8.

```
awk -v FPAT='\\[[^][]*]|"([^"]*)"|\\S+' '{
  if ($8 ~ /(instagram|facebook)\./) {
    gsub(/"/, "", $8)
    print $1, $8
  }
}' access.log
```

Output

```
1.2.3.4 https://l.instagram.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk`

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,/,"");print $1, $13}' input_file
```

`sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/^(.[^ ]*).*"(https.[^"]*).*/\1 \2/' input_file
```

**output**

```
1.2.3.4 https://l.instagram.com/
```